# JBoss 7 stops responding

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x

Occasionally, after I deploy a war to my `standalone/deployments` folder, JBoss starts as usual, deploy the app without any error and.... BLANK PAGE.

It looks like it's not listening to my 8080 port, my requests just don't get executed!

I deploy either manually, or via Eclipse Jboss tools, I tried downloading again latest version of all softwares, even on different OS.

Nothing. 
Then, I try restart the AS... it works, the next restart... it doesn't :((
It's randomic behavior!

I imagine the "web module" (or whatever you call it) of JBoss not firing up at the server start, I compared startup logs of a "working" time to a "not working" one... they're the same.

```
> fabio$
> /Applications/jboss/bin/standalone.sh 
> =========================================================================
> 
>   JBoss Bootstrap Environment
> 
>   JBOSS_HOME: /Applications/jboss
> 
>   JAVA:
> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> 
>   JAVA_OPTS: -d32 -client -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
> -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml
> 
> =========================================================================
> 
> 16:52:36,841 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
> 16:52:37,325 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
> 16:52:37,360 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final
> "Brontes" starting 16:52:38,923 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
> 16:52:38,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http
> management service using socket-binding (management-http) 16:52:38,930
> INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
> 16:52:38,935 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version
> 3.2.3.GA 16:52:38,957 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers 16:52:38,960 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26)
> JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem 16:52:38,970 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31)
> JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem. 16:52:38,984 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940:
> Activating OSGi Subsystem 16:52:38,986 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming
> Subsystem 16:52:38,999 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
> 16:52:39,011 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7)
> JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final 16:52:39,022 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010408: Starting
> JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final) 16:52:39,039 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48)
> JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension 16:52:39,088 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting
> Naming Service 16:52:39,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC
> service thread 1-4) JBAS015400: Bound mail session
> [java:jboss/mail/Default] 16:52:39,151 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread
> Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class
> org.h2.Driver (version 1.3) 16:52:39,232 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread
> Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class
> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1) 16:52:39,245 INFO 
> [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1)
> Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--0.0.0.0-8080 16:52:39,421 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread
> 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/effebiDS]
> 16:52:39,421 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]
> (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source
> [java:jboss/datasources/eyecloud] 16:52:39,422 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread
> 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source
> [java:jboss/datasources/TicketMonsterDS] 16:52:39,422 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread
> 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/svapp]
> 16:52:39,483 INFO 
> [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service
> thread 1-5) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
> 16:52:39,650 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC
> service thread 1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService
> for directory /Applications/jboss/standalone/deployments 16:52:39,658
> INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]
> (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found svapp.war in
> deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called
> svapp.war.dodeploy 16:52:39,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC
> service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on /0.0.0.0:4447
> 16:52:39,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4)
> JBAS017100: Listening on /0.0.0.0:9999 16:52:39,780 INFO 
> [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876:
> Starting deployment of "svapp.war" ... (follows app deployment)
```

What can I check first?

**EDIT**

HTTP response code is indeed 404 (seen in the dev console in chrome), however the error page is not the jboss default one, but a blank page!

Comment: I've seen with Liferay that when a deployment takes a long time to activate, JBoss is showing a blank page in the meantime. Could that be it?

Comment: no the deployment ends up succesfully, then I check and get the blank 404 page

Comment: can you clarify what does your app actually do? what kind of app it is? does it do any special things on startup? what kind of dependencies does it have (jms queues? datasources?)?

Comment: It's a Java EE 6 web application using a few EJBs, JSF2, JPA (datasources correctly working) and <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
 <context-root>/</context-root>
 <virtual-host>svapp</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue was fixed in JBoss 8 (Wildfly). We'll never know :)

Answer (score 0):

If your JBoss were not listening at 8080, you wouldn't receive a blank page, but a connection error from your browser.

And if your application works fine without changing anything in deployment folder after restarting the application, then your application package is correct, but was not deployed/initialized correctly.

Are you using a WAR file or exploded deployment? It may be the case, that your hot deployment does not work correctly. I would suggest to use the "restart application" button in eclipse (starts only the application again within JBoss, but not the JBoss itself) after a deploy - at least I experienced a similar behaviour when trying to hot-deploy from within eclipse.

Comment: I am hot deploying a war. Eclipse (or by myself, manually) puts the war into the /opt/jboss/standalone/deployments directory, so the scanner find and deploy it till the end without errors. I did "restart app" from eclipse a thousand of times... nothing. See my edits

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem while starting the JBOSS 6.0.

Jboss was becoming un responsive with the following error
15:27:19,391 INFO  [service] Removing bootstrap log handlers

The issue I found was the Lock on my log files generated by JBOSS.
Eg : server.log . I removed the log files and then started the server and it went up and running.

Also I found the following article helpfull
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/170190?tstart=0&_sscc=t